# Suppress "[executable].exe has triggered a breakpoint" when debugging an assert

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, native, assert

When native c++ code (in debug) makes an assert, this dialog pops up.[image: Assert Dialog].

Pressing "Retry" (to debug the application), will then cause Visual Studio to show a second, rather redundant, dialog.
[image: Redundant Dialog]

Is there a way to suppress the "... has triggered a breakpoint" and just break?

Comment: Have you tried checking the check box or clicking on the open exceptions setting link?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yup.  I tried checking the checkbox and selecting everything in the Open Exception Settings link.  The dialog will still pop up.  However, the "Break when this exception type is thrown" checkbox will be checked...

Comment: @CurtisHx have you tried to launch debugger break programmatically?